# How to update vuex store based on firestore change

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

I have a vuejs, vuex, firestore app that stores user state using vuex.  All is working fine, however, I have a feature where a user submits a job to an aws lambda which takes a little while to process.

The lambda does its thing, and when it's done it updates a field on the user's document in firestore.  My app needs to reload the user's state into my vuex store, but I don't know how to listen or trigger that action within my app, as the user will submit the long running job and then go on their way.

How can I have my vuejs app be notified that the single document's field has been updated at firestore so I can dispatch and re-load my vuex state?

Comment: [This](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) might help.

Comment: Could you share your existing code (component and vuex)?